# Windows 10 (10.0.14393); how to set registry permissions

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, regedit

I am attempting to fix an "IndirectSound" install so it works with an ancient game called Caesar III. The instructions say I have to modify the registry, so I created a restore point and fired up regedit.

Not surprisingly, I've got permissions issues. I fired up regedit as an admin this time - the machine only has one user, I'm using her account, it's an admin account.

I found the key I was looking for at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{1234} but it tells me I don't have permission to edit a value within that, or to delete a value or create a new one.

I went into permissions for {1234} and set the permissions for the account I'm using to "full control" - same errors. I went back and set the option for "allow inheritance", same errors.

How do I go about changing permissions so that I can edit the keys to try to get IndirectSound working?

Comment: You need to take ownership of that key.

Comment: I have to have ownership? Then why have all those levels of permissions? If I have to be the owner to change it, what is the point of setting "full access" on someone who isn't the owner? I will go try to take ownership and see if that helps, it's just confusing that I have to.

Comment: ok, evidently I already did take ownership -- Owner is listed as "name (LAPTOP-GIBBERISH\name), with a link to "Change" to the right at the top of the advanced security settings. It didn't change the error messages. I went into "Effective Access" and typed 'name', clicked "Check Names" which transformed into the longer form (starting with LAPTOP), then clicked "View effective access", and it shows "Full Control" and 10 other permissions with green checks on top of that double-user icon.

Comment: Ok, have to take ownership of the parent key AND the key containing the value I want to change, evidently. Thanks.